# Duplicity fails with "too many open files" error

Tags: backup, gnupg, duplicity, ulimit

Duplicity won't backup anymore.  I'm running the same backup script as I have for months, but something has apparently changed.

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: can't open `/home/username/.gnupg/random_seed': Too many open files
gpg: fatal: can't open /dev/urandom: Too many open files
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir `/home/username/.gnupg'
secmem usage: 2400/2400 bytes in 6/6 blocks of pool 2400/65536
===== End GnuPG log =====

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
100000
```

Can I fix it with ulimit? How?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `ulimit -n` ?

To increase the value for the current shell, you can do `ulimit -n 100000`.